# What is the way to say "work by Scrum"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Scrum is a popular way of organizing software development process. There are also other ways, for example, the Waterfall method. Let's suppose I want to say that our company or the members of our project's team organize their work using Scrum method or Waterfall method:

- *We used to **work by waterfall**, but now we are **working by scrum***.

Or do natives say it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could write "We used to work by waterfall" but it is a little awkward and unnatural in my view. More likely would be:

- > We used to organize our work by the waterfall method
- > We used to use the waterfall method
- > We used to follow the waterfall procedure
- > We used to do waterfall development

Any of "process", "system", "procedure", "pattern", or "protocol" could be used in place of "method" in the aboe examples. Other terms could also be used.

By the way almost no one does pure waterfall development, and this has been true for decades. Virtually everyone uses some version of an iterative cycle. The scrum people like to contrast their system with waterfall development. This is a bit like an ad for a new printer explaining how much better it is than using a sip pen. It is true but not very relevant. I write as one who has been a full time professional software developer for several  decades, and is officially scrum-certified.

Comment: Thank you a lot! So you really never say just "work by Scrum" or "follow Scrum"? It's so short and simple and more lazy than saying "work by Scrum method" or "follow Scrum development".

Comment: @Daniel I would never say "We work by Scrum." and I never recall hearing that. I might well say "we follow Scrum" or "we use Scrum" or particularly "we follow Scrum, but in a modified form". It is really the ":work by" that seems awkward.